# List of smart pointers - Managing object lifetime and pointer validity

Tags: c++, list, constructor, c++11, smart-pointers

I have a list of smart pointers where each pointer points to a separate Entity class.

`std::list<std::unique_ptr<Entity>> m_entities;`

I would like the constructor to handle the assigning of each pointer to a std::list class as it is "automatically" handled by the code on class instantiation. However, if this design is bad then I would welcome a better alternative as it only makes sense to me coming from a C# background.

```
Entity::Entity(Game &game) 
    : m_game(game),             
    m_id(m_game.g_idGenerator->generateNewID())             
{
    m_game.m_entities.push_back(std::unique_ptr<Entity>(this));
}
```

The main problem I have encountered with this method is that the Entity class' lifetime is unmanaged by the Entity class.

For example if I allocate an Entity class on the stack it will call the Entity destructor after leaving the method in which it was allocated and the pointer will no longer be valid.

I therefore considered the alternative of creating a smart pointer, allocating the Entity class to the heap and then explicitly adding the pointer to the list.

```
std::unique_ptr<Entity> b(new Entity(*this));
m_entities.push_back(b);   // ERROR
```

This produces the following error

```
error C2664: 'void std::list<_Ty>::push_back(_Ty &&)' : cannot convert parameter 1 from 'std::unique_ptr<_Ty>' to 'std::unique_ptr<_Ty> &&'
```

What would be considered the best approach for allocating each pointer to the list and is a constructor based version possible?

I'm currently thinking that it is the list of smart pointers that should handle the lifetime for each Entity class and that assigning pointers in a constructor is not a good design choice.  In that case I should probably create a CreateEntity method that adds the pointer to list rather than let the constructor handle it.  Is this better?

I considered what type of smart pointer would be appropriate for this operation after reading through questions found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/94227/smart-pointers-or-who-owns-you-baby), [here](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/133302/stdshared-ptr-as-a-last-resort) and [here](http://www.allegro.cc/forums/thread/601189) (offsite).  It is difficult to get an exact answer based on what I've read so far though as they all offer somewhat conflicting advice.

Comment: Why does your code use `std::unique_ptr<T>` but the error message use `std::auto_ptr<T>`?

Comment: Is this your real code? `std::unique_ptr` and `std::auto_ptr` are different unrelated classes, and the code you showed is using `std::unque_ptr` but the error message says `std::auto_ptr` instead. And how is `Boundary` related to `Entity`?

Comment: See this: http://stackoverflow.com/a/2880062/1463922

Comment: The wrong error was copied by mistake as I was changing between pointer types to see the difference they made.  Apologies.  It has been edited to show the correct error.

Comment: Related http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8114276/how-do-i-pass-a-unique-ptr-argument-to-a-constructor-or-a-function

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Using constructor this way is definitely not good idea because constructor has no information about how object is created and controlled - on the stack, statically, dynamically by some smart pointer, dynamically by dumb pointer?

To solve this problem you could use static factory method to create `Entity` instances:

```
class Entity
{
public:

   // Variant with unique ownership
   static void CreateGameEntity(Game& game)
   {
     std::unique_ptr<Entity> p(new Entity());
     game.m_entities.push_back(std::move(p));
   }

   // OR (you cannot use both)

   // Variant with shared ownership
   static std::shared_ptr<Entity> CreateGameEntity(Game& game)
   {
     std::shared_ptr<Entity> p(new Entity());
     game.m_entities.push_back(p);
     return p;
   }

private:

   // Declare ctors private to avoid possibility to create Entity instances
   // without CreateGameEntity() method, e.g. on stack.
   Entity();
   Entity(const Entity&);
};
```

Which smart pointer to use? Well, this depends on your design. If `Game` object solely owns `Entity` instances and completely manages their lifetime, using [`std::unique_ptr`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/unique_ptr) is OK. If you need some kind of shared ownership (e.g. you have several `Game` objects that can share same `Entity` objects) you shall use [`std::shared_ptr`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/shared_ptr).

Also in case of unique ownership you may use [Boost Pointer Container library](http://www.boost.org/libs/ptr_container/doc/ptr_container.html). It contains specialized owning pointer containers like `ptr_vector`, `ptr_list`, `ptr_map` etc.

Comment: _If you need some kind of shared ownership (e.g. you have several Game objects that can share same Entity objects) you shall use std::shared_ptr_  Other classes will access the pointer via the std:list that owns/holds all the pointers.  These other classes may get or set exposed Entity parameters.  Do they need to own the object to do this?

Comment: @user1423893 : "Own" in this context means to control (or extend) an object's lifetime.

Answer (score 3):

I won't comment on your design questions, but to fix your error, change your code to either:

```
m_entities.push_back(std::unique_ptr<Boundary>(new Boundary(*this, body)));
```

or:

```
std::unique_ptr<Boundary> b(new Boundary(*this, body));
m_entities.push_back(std::move(b));
```

The reason is that `b` in your code is an lvalue, but `std::unique_ptr<>` is a move-only type (i.e. has no copy constructor).

Comment: This answer deserves more visibility.

Answer (score 3):

The problem in your code is that you try to move a `std::unique_ptr<T>` from an l-value. The instantiations of `std::unique_ptr<T>` are non-copyable and are only movable. To move from an l-value you need to explicitly do so:

```
this->m_entities.push_back(std::move(b));
```

The call to `std::move()` won't really move anything but it does yield a type which indicates to the compiler that the object can be moved.

Answer (score 0):

To address the issue with the stack-created instance, you could simply add a parameter to the constructor that tells it to not add the new instance to the list, eg:

```
Entity::Entity(Game &game, bool AddToList = true)  
    : m_game(game),              
      m_id(m_game.g_idGenerator->generateNewID())              
{ 
    if (AddToList) m_game.m_entities.push_back(this); 
}
```

.

```
{
    ...
    Entity e(game, false);
    ...
}
```

Another option might be to add a destructor to Entity that removes it from the list if it is still present, but that might get a little complex trying to avoid conflicts between direct `Entity` destructions and `unique_ptr` destructions.