# Has C++11 changed requirements for elements of STL containers, and how?

Tags: c++, stl, c++11

Recently I'm surprised at the fact [`std::unique_ptr` is acceptable for elements of STL containers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2876641/so-can-unique-ptr-be-used-safely-in-stl-collections), because I thought these elements are required to provide functions below([this page](http://www.processdoc.com/cppstl/objreq.html) says the same):

- public default constructor with no arguments
- public copy constructor
- public copy assignment operator function
- public destructor

But `std::unique_ptr` is not copyable to make the pointer it holds owned by a single object, that contradicts the requirements above.

Has the standard changed the requirements? If so, what are the changes? Perhaps either movable objects or copyable ones are sufficient?
I've searched the web whether the requirements has changed since C++11, but I can't find any page which helps me...

Comment: I believe C++11 requires a copy constructor *or a move constructor* (similarly, copy assignment or move assignment).

Comment: "*Has C++11 changed requirements for elements of STL containers?*" Yes, very much so. Have you read even obvious places e.g. [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C%2B%2B11) before asking?

Comment: @ildjarn okay then, I edited my question so that my intention is clearly expressed.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Yes, there have been major changes to the requirements for standard library containers. It's hard to provide a comprehensive list (there were a *lot*), but here are some important ones:

`std::vector` generally requires only that its members be [MoveConstructible](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/concept/MoveConstructible) and [MoveAssignable](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/concept/MoveAssignable). There are many member functions of std::vector that impose more strict requirements. `vector::push_back` requires Move *or* [CopyConstructible](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/concept/CopyConstructible) (depending on whether you pass an rvalue or lvalue), but the new `vector::emplace_back` only requires that there is an accessible constructor that takes the given parameters (in addition to the baseline requirement). Obviously any attempt to invoke the `vector`'s copy constructor/assignment will require that the type be CopyConstructible (ie: you can't copy a `std::vector<unique_ptr>`).

Similarly, most other containers have reduced the restrictions on the type. They also have `emplace` member functions that allow you to construct the members in-place, as well as l/rvalue insertion functions. Which means that you don't have to copy values in; you can move them in or construct them in-place.

None of the constructors or destructors are *required* to be public; all construction takes place via calls to `allocator_traits<Allocator>::construct` calls. So if you provide an allocator, you could make your constructors/destructors private. Well, as long as your allocator class can access them, of course.

In short, the requirements are much less strict, but they're a bit more complex. You can get away with a lot of things if you restrict yourself from performing certain operations on the container.

Comment: What do you refer to when you need to know requirements of specific operations? Anyone who read this page will be benefited.

Comment: @NicolBoras: Oh, that requires reading of the standard... I'll grab one. Thank you!

Comment: vector::emplace_back still requires that the elements be moveable/copyable, since it may grow the vector.

Comment: @Nevin: yes, more specifically, since it cannot be statically eliminated that `emplace_back` may grow the vector, even if the capacity is sufficient it is deemed necessary that the elements can be either copied or moved.

Comment: @Nevin: As I said, "*There are many member functions of std::vector that have more strict requirements.*" Followed by listing some of those more strict requirements. All of those requirements are *in addition to* the move requirement.