# unable to find what causes a compile time error

Tags: c++11, mingw, diagnostics

I'm using MinGW 4.8.0 (included in QtCreator 5.1) with C++11.
The problem is that I get a compile time error but I can not find the source of the error.

```
typedef std::unique_ptr< ADMessageReqRSSingle > MsgType; 
typedef std::vector< MsgType > Cont; 
typedef Cont::const_iterator MsgCIter; 

Cont mCont; // Inside another clas
```

Is there a diagnostic tool that is a little more specific?

The gcc log is the following:

```
Makefile.Debug:1491: recipe for target 'debug/adsync.o' failed
In file included from c:\qt\tools\mingw48_32\lib\gcc\i686-w64-mingw32\4.8.0\include\c++\memory:64:0,
                     from ..\aams/iocontroller/iocontroller.hpp:15,
                     from ..\aams/aams/aamscontext.h:13,
                     from ..\aams\src\aams\adsync.cpp:8:
    c:\qt\tools\mingw48_32\lib\gcc\i686-w64-mingw32\4.8.0\include\c++\bits\stl_construct.h: In instantiation of 'void std::_Construct(_T1*, _Args&& ...) [with _T1 = std::unique_ptr<aams::device::ADMessageReqRSSingle>; _Args = {const std::unique_ptr<aams::device::ADMessageReqRSSingle, std::default_delete<aams::device::ADMessageReqRSSingle> >&}]':
    c:\qt\tools\mingw48_32\lib\gcc\i686-w64-mingw32\4.8.0\include\c++\bits\stl_uninitialized.h:75:53:   required from 'static _ForwardIterator std::__uninitialized_copy<_TrivialValueTypes>::__uninit_copy(_InputIterator, _InputIterator, _ForwardIterator) [with _InputIterator = __gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<const std::unique_ptr<aams::device::ADMessageReqRSSingle>*, std::vector<std::unique_ptr<aams::device::ADMessageReqRSSingle> > >; _ForwardIterator = std::unique_ptr<aams::device::ADMessageReqRSSingle>*; bool _TrivialValueTypes = false]'
    c:\qt\tools\mingw48_32\lib\gcc\i686-w64-mingw32\4.8.0\include\c++\bits\stl_uninitialized.h:117:41:   required from '_ForwardIterator std::uninitialized_copy(_InputIterator, _InputIterator, _ForwardIterator) [with _InputIterator = __gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<const std::unique_ptr<aams::device::ADMessageReqRSSingle>*, std::vector<std::unique_ptr<aams::device::ADMessageReqRSSingle> > >; _ForwardIterator = std::unique_ptr<aams::device::ADMessageReqRSSingle>*]'
    c:\qt\tools\mingw48_32\lib\gcc\i686-w64-mingw32\4.8.0\include\c++\bits\stl_uninitialized.h:258:63:   required from '_ForwardIterator std::__uninitialized_copy_a(_InputIterator, _InputIterator, _ForwardIterator, std::allocator<_Tp>&) [with _InputIterator = __gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<const std::unique_ptr<aams::device::ADMessageReqRSSingle>*, std::vector<std::unique_ptr<aams::device::ADMessageReqRSSingle> > >; _ForwardIterator = std::unique_ptr<aams::device::ADMessageReqRSSingle>*; _Tp = std::unique_ptr<aams::device::ADMessageReqRSSingle>]'
    c:\qt\tools\mingw48_32\lib\gcc\i686-w64-mingw32\4.8.0\include\c++\bits\stl_vector.h:316:32:   required from 'std::vector<_Tp, _Alloc>::vector(const std::vector<_Tp, _Alloc>&) [with _Tp = std::unique_ptr<aams::device::ADMessageReqRSSingle>; _Alloc = std::allocator<std::unique_ptr<aams::device::ADMessageReqRSSingle> >]'
    ..\aams/aams/device/admessagereq.h:687:50:   required from here
    c:\qt\tools\mingw48_32\lib\gcc\i686-w64-mingw32\4.8.0\include\c++\bits\stl_construct.h:75:7: error: use of deleted function 'std::unique_ptr<_Tp, _Dp>::unique_ptr(const std::unique_ptr<_Tp, _Dp>&) [with _Tp = aams::device::ADMessageReqRSSingle; _Dp = std::default_delete<aams::device::ADMessageReqRSSingle>]'
         { ::new(static_cast<void*>(__p)) _T1(std::forward<_Args>(__args)...); }
           ^
    In file included from c:\qt\tools\mingw48_32\lib\gcc\i686-w64-mingw32\4.8.0\include\c++\memory:81:0,
                     from ..\aams/iocontroller/iocontroller.hpp:15,
                     from ..\aams/aams/aamscontext.h:13,
                     from ..\aams\src\aams\adsync.cpp:8:
    c:\qt\tools\mingw48_32\lib\gcc\i686-w64-mingw32\4.8.0\include\c++\bits\unique_ptr.h:273:7: error: declared here
           unique_ptr(const unique_ptr&) = delete;
           ^
```

Comment: where is the code? Is there any question-posing tool that can make this more specific :/ ?

Comment: are you trying to create a container with `unique_ptr`?

Comment: He's trying to copy a unique_ptr, as a part of a vector. Yes. @elvis: unique pointers can't be copyable, because... they wouldn't be very unique anymore

Comment: @KirilKirov yes I'm trying to create a `vector` of `unique_ptr` of `ADMessageReqRSSingle`

Comment: @elvis.dukaj That'd have been the code to show then

Comment: `typedef std::unique_ptr< ADMessageReqRSSingle > MsgType;`
`typedef std::vector< MsgType  > Cont;`
`typedef Cont::const_iterator MsgCIter;` `Cont mCont`. Inside another class

Comment: so have I to use shared_ptr?

Comment: @elvis.dukaj Impossible to tell without more code. See [So can unique_ptr be used safely in stl collections](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2876641/so-can-unique-ptr-be-used-safely-in-stl-collections) for a good start though

Answer (score 1, accepted):

<sub>Based on the errors and on your answer to my comment:</sub>
You can't have container with `unique_ptr` as it's not copy-constructable, which is necessary for all STL containers.

Comment: But the code above worked. The class `ADMessageReqRSSingle` is moveable. I changed the code to add the `clone` method to the base class of `ADMessageReqRSSingle`. After that it stopped to work.

Comment: The "problem" is in `unique_ptr`, not in your class. The container is from `unique_ptr`, which has "`delete`"d copy constructor. Check this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2876641/so-can-unique-ptr-be-used-safely-in-stl-collections

Comment: @elvis Please: "The code above worked"? There ***is no code***. See http://sscce.org/

Comment: I know I cannot post the code. But the same code first worked. After adding the prototype design patter I had the issue

Comment: @elvis.dukaj How is that "the same code then"? Pro tip: don't fool yourself with victim logic. Look at the facts: the _changes_ you made introduced a compilation failure. Now, you will be able to search for the problem.

Comment: I just want to understand... isn't victimism! The fact are: First: I had a vector of `unique_ptr< MyClass >` and the code builds and works fine. `MyClass` is contructable and movable. Later I had to add the prototype design pattern. So I add to `IMyClass`, base class of `MyClass`, the method `virtual unique_ptr< IMyClass > clone() const = 0`. I also implemnt the method to `MyClass`. After that I had that issue. I just want to understand why first code compiles fine and after not...

Comment: Plain wrong. For most stl container operations move semantics is enough.

Answer (score 1):

You have something like:

```
class A
{
public:
    A() {}
private:
    std::vector<std::unique_ptr<int>> ints;
};
```

So, A is not copyable (because `unique_ptr` is not),
To have better error message, you may add explicitly

```
    A(const A&) = delete;
    A& operator = (const A&) = delete;
```

Following code shows your error message.

```
int main() {
    A a, b;

    a = b; // Error appears due to this copy 
    return 0;
}
```

You may use `move` instead of copy if appropriate.

```
int main() {
    A a, b;

    a = std::move(b); // No error, but b is now "invalid"
    return 0;
}
```

EDIT: Just see your comment about Clone in comment in another answer:

Clone is a copy (and A is not copyable so an error).

you may use (if appropriate) something like:

```
std::unique_ptr<A> A::Clone() const {
    std::unique_ptr<A> res(new A());
    for (auto i : ints) {
        // copy the value, not the pointer.
        res->ints.push_back(std::unique_ptr<int>(new int(*i)));
    }
    return res;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

> Items in a vector must be assignable (or, in more recent versions of the standard, movable).

- See the answer of [Jerry Coffin](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17313104/3681671)

You compiler does not seem to be recent enough to accept the moveable part.
Another possible reason anyone might get this error if you made a vector of const objects which are also not assignable.