# Why unique_ptr works but auto_ptr doesn’t with STL

Tags: c++, stl, copy-constructor, unique-ptr, auto-ptr

I have referred to lot of StackOverflow links on these questions where the reason for `auto_ptr` not working well with STL is 
`std::auto_ptr<>` does not fulfill the requirements of being copy-constructible and assignable (since `auto_ptr` has a fake copy constructor which basically transfers the ownership).

But even `unique_ptr` doesn't have copy ctor and assignment operator (it's disabled), so how is the requirement of being copy-constructible and assignable fulfilled?

Comment: Do you have a particular example of something that requires copying but works with `unique_ptr`?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You're looking at the whole thing backwards.

In C++98/03, we got `auto_ptr`. This type lies to everyone by pretending that it supports copy semantics when in fact copying it does something very much unlike a copy operation. Therefore, any type which relies on a type providing copy semantics, like certain containers, would not take well to getting an `auto_ptr`. Of course, you will only find out when your code becomes dysfunctional, not at compile time.

In C++11, we got `unique_ptr`, a type which explicitly does not provide copy semantics. Instead, it provides move semantics, and provides them correctly. Therefore, any type which relies on a type providing copy semantics will fail to compile when given a `unique_ptr`.

*However*, the reason `unique_ptr` came into being at all because the concept of moving an object was added to the language in C++11. When new concepts get added to the language, existing tools, like standard library requirements, are often re-evaluated relative to that language feature.

For example, types that formerly required copy semantics did not necessarily have to keep that requirement. C++98/03 containers that required copy semantics were updated in C++11 to only require (noexcept) move semantics from a type.

So it's not that `unique_ptr` fulfills some requirement that `auto_ptr` did not. It's that the language changed to no longer need that requirement, but `auto_ptr` was still lying about what it did, so for backwards compatibility sake, we created a new type that respected the new language features and didn't lie to people.

Comment: Your answer is worth 20 other detailed posts on stackoverflow. Thsi is what i was looking for - about the change in standard which changed the requirement and ptr usage.

Answer (score 1):

I assume you're referring to using smart pointers with STL containers.

`auto_ptr` can, but *shouldn't* be used because its copy constructor may accidentally move data (it was designed before move semantics with rvalue references were added in C++11).

`unique_ptr` doesn't have a copy constructor, so it can't be trivially used in STL containers. Operations that copy the pointer won't work, but that's what makes it safe. You can still explicitly use [move iterators](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/iterator/move_iterator) or emplace to get noncopyable elements into containers.

Examples for using `unique_ptr` in containers here:
[So can unique_ptr be used safely in stl collections?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2876641/so-can-unique-ptr-be-used-safely-in-stl-collections)

Comment: Yep. Got it. By trivially do you mean “always”?

Comment: Nope. Just some of the things you casually do with `vector<int>` won't work with `unique_ptr`. If you `push_back` a `unique_ptr`, you'll get a nasty error. But if you `emplace_back` one, you might not. See the link for examples.

Comment: @parktomatomi push_back works just fine with unique_ptr as long as the argument is an rvalue.

Answer (score 1):

auto_ptr looks like copy constructible / assignable, because it has a copy constructor and assignment operator.

The problem is that its copy constructor and assignment don't implement copy semantics, but move semantics instead. This makes the interface of auto_ptr surprising, and makes it unusable in containers that assign elements internally (such as vector).

What makes this worse is that using auto_ptr in a vector is well-formed (no compilation error), but doesn't have useful behaviour, which can easily lead to undefined behaviour (i.e. serious bugs).

> But even unique_ptr doesn't have copy ctor and assignment operator(its disabled)

unique_ptr doesn't need to be copy constructible or assignable. It is sufficient to be move constructible and assignable for most use cases.

unique_ptr can replace all uses of auto_ptr, and doesn't have the problems of auto_ptr. Since C++11 where unique_ptr as well as language support for moving was introduced, auto_ptr has been deprecated and since C++17, auto_ptr has been removed from the standard library.

Comment: my confusion is more towards "requirements of being copy-constructible and assignable of STL" is not still being fulfilled by unique_ptr. And the example you gave about _"makes the interface of auto_ptr surprising, and makes it unusable in containers that assign elements internally (such as vector)."_ eventually the end result is the same in case of unique_ptr too - i.e. data is moved  and not copied. auto_ptr moves it through copy, unqiue_ptr does it through move. So then in such cases, what has changes that we prefer unique_ptr

Comment: @anurag86 Copying of unique_ptr is not surprising at all. It is fully expected that it cannot be copied. The compiler will tell it to you relatively clearly, if you think otherwise.

Comment: @anurag86 Nothing changed in auto_ptr. It was always a flawed design. There simply wasn't a better alternative when C++ was standardised. It was usually recommended to be avoided even before its deprecation. What changed was the C++ language and the introduction of move semantics and in particular, the introduction of the unique_ptr type into the language. Unique_ptr is all that auto_ptr was supposed to be, but couldn't be because there wasn't move semantics in the language.